# edit.blade.php is not reading my variable

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to return variable to my edit view but for whatever reason my variable is not readable in my edit view.

here is my Controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $student = Student::find($id);




   return view('student.edit', compact('student'));



        }
```

my edit view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')


<form action="{{action('StudentsController@update','id')}}" method="POST">

            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstName">First Name </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fName" id="elastName" value="$student->StudentFName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastName">Last name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lName" id="efirstName" value="$student->StudentLName">
            </div>
</form>


<?php 

echo $student->id;
?>
@endsection
```

as you can i did a php code and its working fine but its working only if i used variable inside php which is weird because im used to workd with variables without using . Can you please help me.

Comment: Try `{{ $student->id }}`

Comment: To echo a variable in Blade, you need to place it between double curly brackets (including the values in your input tags `{{$student->StudentLName}}`

Comment: yes its working.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{}}` in value to get the values.which is equals to  in laravel for blade templates.